# Asynchronous and Synchronous functions behavior in one blocking line

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-5

I have this Synchronous function :

```
void AddItem(Item item)
{
    _context.Items.Add(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

and the Asynchronous function :

```
async Task AddItemAsync(Item item)
{
    _context.Items.Add(item);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Do these functions have any difference at all ? I have a lot of functions like these in my project. just get an instance of an object, CRUD in database and return the result. Do I need to define my functions Asynchronous ? I saw a video that says Asynchronous programming is much better. I know if I have a blocking call and some independent work, it's better to use Asynchronous programming. But what about here ? And I must say that in the video he chooses to use code block 2nd. 
Do I gain advantages from code block 2 ?

### EDIT:

I know the pattern of async/await and its usage. My question is that both functions have similar behavior (not in thread pool) but is there any advantages that code block 2 has in this particular scenario ?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: Thanks but it was not helpful. I am familiar with the Asynchronous programming. I want to know that the code block 2nd has advantages from code block first or not.

Comment: The second is generally more scalable. The question boils down to what is the *async and await pattern*, this has been asked and answered many times. There are also 1000's blogs out there dedicated to this topic

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "SaveChangesAsync()" really starts a new task (i.e. with Task.Run()), code block 2 is asynchronous.
But the task may be running in the UI-thread (main process thread), when he's free at the moment.
That's why you see no used threadpool thread.

So code block 2 does not block the caller (calling thread) and returns immediately.

Regards

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't mention I am using .Netcore WebAPI. So the user trigger the controller, and the controller awaits the code block 2 (in repository). so to sum up a controller wants to add an item to context and save to database. no UI here. you prefer to make the controller and AddItem function asynchronous or synchronous ?

Comment: UI thread = "process main thread". There is no difference. I would prefer async methods over non async. But be aware: sometimes async DB-methods dispatch internally to synchronous implementations (depends on DB-provider)! So they are not really async. Only thread-debugger will tell.
What DB-provider you are using?

Comment: Oh you are right. I am using EntityFrameworkCore. (MSSQL and PostgresSQL)
So That makes sense. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: MSSQL has a fully async implementation of all async database methods. For PostgresSQL i'm really certain they route to the synchronous once internally. It's just a default impl to support async methods, but internally they are sync.